# Stop timer when user input is submitted - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to stop a timer when user input is entered

Ex. Someone enters a string, hits enter, and then the timer stops and records the amount of time it took for that string to be entered

Here is what i have so far, but it isn't right.

```
import time

count=0
stopthetimer = -1
while stopthetimer <0:
    time.sleep(1)
    count +=1
    result = raw_input()
    stopthetimer +=1
```

tried to make it so when result is finished, it goes to stopthetimer, which stops the loop.

Answer (score 6):

Just record the time before and after the `raw_input()` call:

```
import time

before = time.time()
result = raw_input()
after = time.time()

time_user_input = after-before
```